Apache Spark in Account A read Aws DataCatalog of Account B with Assumed-Role
I work on a solution on AWS to launch query from Account A on tables from Account B with assumed-role.
The necessary policy is configured in both accounts and I'm able to launch this query using lambda from Account A to get data from Account B, with boto3, assumed-role, session.
This case proves 1. the necessary policy is given to account A to assume Account B and Account B has access to target catalog for the query execution.
But I want to run the same query from glue job directly with apache spark, so I can get query result and write a single file to my s3 bucket in one job, instead of Lambda + Glue.
I tried a couple of days and I only make my glue job in Account A to read data from s3 inside Account B, but my glue job can only see databases from Account A. I wonder if that's technically possible.
import sys
import boto3
import time
import boto3.session
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from awsglue.context import GlueContext

sts_client_default = boto3.client('sts')
tenant_data = {
    "bucket": "targe-bucket-account-b",
    "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam:::role/account-b-role-to-assume",
    "kms_key_arn": "arn:aws:kms:::key/xxx",
    "s3_file_path": "s3a://bucket-in-account-b/0d448cfe-3d5f-4a22-8bd9-4ebf2a0552e9.csv"
}
response_data = sts_client_default.assume_role(RoleArn=tenant_data["role_arn"], RoleSessionName='AssumeRoleSession')
credentials_data = response_data['Credentials']
SPARK_CONF = [
    ("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "4g")
]
SPARK_CONF += [
    (
        "fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider",
        "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider"
    ),
    ("fs.s3a.access.key", credentials_data['AccessKeyId']
    ),
    ("fs.s3a.secret.key", credentials_data['SecretAccessKey']
    ),
    ("fs.s3a.session.token", credentials_data['SessionToken']
    )]
spark.sql("show databases").show(100, False) # only databases from account A are showing here
spark.read.csv(tenant_data["s3_file_path"]).show(5, False) # spark read bucket from account B and it works
spark.sql("use corp_cdm_raw_ifo_atr") # I want to use database from account B and it failed here, saying that spark cannot find this database.

I wonder what conf I'm missing here, if my idea is doable.
according to this doc, my idea is doable in the same account, but I donot know how to do for cross account.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-data-catalog-hive.html
